# Listed dictionaries from list inside a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have data like

```
{'message_text': '*प्रशासक समिति*',
'translated_text': '* Administrator ',
'annotation_list': ['Fear speech', 'Fear speech', 'Normal'],
'propagation': [{'group_id': 9087,
'user_id': 229869,
'timestamp': 1538130086000},
{'group_id': 7, 'user_id': 215, 'timestamp': 1550186113000}]}


current code
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fear_speech_data, orient='index')
```

Currently, I am able to read the code with only four columns

```
message_text    
translated_text 
annotation_list 
propagation
```

I would like to read the above details into a data frame with the following columns in the dataframe

```
message_text    
translated_text 
annotation_list 
propagation
group_id
user_id
timestamp
group_id
user_id
timestamp
```

Comment: First you shouldnot/cannot have columns with the same name. Second, your data only has 2 columns. Where do you want to get the otherss from? If the others are columns then does that mean your df is multiindexed?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** based on data link

I took the values out of the json provided because it wasn't easy to work with, but I think it's what you want

```
from flatten_json import flatten
url ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hate-alert/Fear-speech-analysis/master/Data/fear_speech_data.json'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)

#list(data.values())
    
dic_flattened = (flatten(d, '.') for d in list(data.values()))
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

Output

```
                                           message_text                                    translated_text annotation_list.0 annotation_list.1  ... propagation.241.group_id  propagation.241.user_id  propagation.241.timestamp  propagation
0     *प्रशासक समिति*✊  ●●●●●●●●●●● ● ● ●  *आंतकव...  * Administrator ✊    Committee * ● ●●●●●●●●●●...       Fear speech       Fear speech  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
1     हैदराबाद की मक्का मस्जिद में ब्लास्ट 16 मरे 10...  Blast 16 killed and 100 injured in Hyderabad's...            Normal            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
2     *(1) - "इस्लाम धर्म नहीं एक मानसिक रोग है" - श...  * (1) - "Islam is not a religion but a mental ...       Fear speech       Fear speech  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
3     पाकिस्तान से अधिक तो जमात-ए-इस्लामी के संसाधन ...  Jamaat-e-Islami has more resources than Pakist...       Fear speech            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
4     शहरी नक्सलवाद माओवाद । बस एक निवेदन ... पढ़ना ...  Urban Naxalism Maoism. Just a request… start r...            Normal            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
...                                                 ...                                                ...               ...               ...  ...                      ...                      ...                        ...          ...
4777  हिन्दुओं से बेशर्म कोई जाति पूरा पढ़े कठोर वचन...  I also apologize to the Hindus for the shamele...       Fear speech            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
4778  अब भी नही जागे तो मधेपुरा पूर्णिया में भी हिंद...  Even if you do not wake up, then in Madhepura ...       Fear speech       Fear speech  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
4779  इतिहास का सबसे बड़ा छल हिंदुओं के साथ हुआ  मुस...  The biggest trick of history happened to Hindu...            Normal            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN           []
4780  फिर कहते हैं #राममन्दिर नहीं बना _____________...  Then it says #Ramandir is not made ___________...       Fear speech       Fear speech  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN
4781  *उर्दू हिन्दुस्तान के देशभक्त क्रांतिकारियों क...  * Urdu is the tongue of the patriotic revoluti...            Normal            Normal  ...                      NaN                      NaN                        NaN          NaN

[4782 rows x 732 columns]
```

Comment: Hello, it is working fine for one item in the dictionary but not for multiple items, any solution for that?

Comment: Post more data please. And the exact syntax of the overall structure. Most likely your example isn’t representative of the data you have. But let’s see.

Comment: please find it at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hate-alert/Fear-speech-analysis/master/Data/fear_speech_data.json